# Si el valor es "si" mostrar algo (un icono por ejemplo)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy haciendo una web y aprendiendo al mismo tiempo, necesito hacer que se muestre un icono en un perfil solo si el usuario es moderador.. en la db está en la tabla "user" un registro (o no se el nombre correcto) llamado moderador (si/no)

Uso php codeigniter

Por ejemplo quiero que muestre esto: `<i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:#359c9c"></i>`

Comment: Te sugiero formular únicamente una pregunta basada en el documento [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero obtienes el valor del campo moderador y se lo envías a la vista.

Luego dentro de tu html puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php if ($moderador == 'si'): ?>
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="color:#359c9c"></i>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Con eso solo mostrará el ícono solo si $moderador es igual a 'si'

Comment: Gracias..genio!